# Intellij Android - White area appears at the bottom of the activity

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio, listview

In my ListView activity, a large white area appears at the bottom of my activity and I can't figure out why and how to fix it, as to why I'm here, it's a listview that uses objects in an arraylist, a custom adapter and an xml template filled with the object data within the listview. Hope this information helps and any help is greatly appreciated because I'm totally lost.

activity_product_list.xml (list activity)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ProductList"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbarnormal"
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lstProducts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="true">



        </ListView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ProductListLayout.xml (Template)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/bodyLight">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relProductContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProductPic"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:padding="5dp"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Product name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgProductPic"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProductPrice"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="£49.99"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtProductName"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
        />


        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etProductAmount"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtProductPrice"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddToBasket"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgProductPic"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btnAddToBasket"
                android:text="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
        />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddToBasket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add to basket"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtProductPrice"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgProductPic"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ProductList.java

```js
package com.example.jack.cbdcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgbtnBack;
    private ListView lstProducts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        lstProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstProducts);

        ArrayList<ProductObject> productObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<ProductObject>();

            ProductObject productObject = new ProductObject("Love Hemp™ 800mg 8% CBD Oil – 10ml", "A bottle contains 800MG of CBD Oil – 8% Purity in 10ml",
                "Certified Organic Hemp.\n" +
                        "Non-GMO, Vegan friendly, CO2 Extracted.\n" +
                        "Fast-Acting.\n" +
                        "Peppermint flavour available.\n" +
                        "Sourced from High-CBD Hemp cultivated in the US.\n" +
                        "Strict GMP Manufacturing & Quality Control process.\n" +
                        "Public Third-Party Lab Test Results.",
                    "https://i1.wp.com/benefitcbduk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/what-are-the-benefits-of-cbd.jpg?fit=1200%2C1200&ssl=1", 49.99);

        ProductObject productObject2 = new ProductObject("Koi CBD – Multi-Purpose CBD Vape or Tincture Oil (250MG-1000MG)",
                "A novel Cannabidiol product from Koi CBD, the Multi-Purpose CBD Vape E-liquid or Tincture CBD Oil. Can’t decide whether to buy Vape or CBD Oil? Why not do both?",
                " No Flavoured Additives.\n" +
                        "> Non-Psychoactive (Zero THC).\n" +
                        "> Hexane Free.\n" +
                        "> GMO Free.\n" +
                        "> Pesticide Free.\n" +
                        "> Multi-Purpose – Perfect vape juice to add to other e-liquids and ideal for use as a tincture or to add to other foods/drinks.",
                "https://i2.wp.com/benefitcbduk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/koi-cbd-250-gold.png?fit=1080%2C1080&ssl=1", 44.99);

            productObjectArrayList.add(productObject);
            productObjectArrayList.add(productObject2);

            ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, R.layout.productlistlayout, productObjectArrayList);
            lstProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.basket:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Basket.class));
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

ProductObject.java

```js
package com.example.jack.cbdcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgbtnBack;
    private ListView lstProducts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        lstProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstProducts);

        ArrayList<ProductObject> productObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<ProductObject>();

            ProductObject productObject = new ProductObject("Love Hemp™ 800mg 8% CBD Oil – 10ml", "A bottle contains 800MG of CBD Oil – 8% Purity in 10ml",
                "Certified Organic Hemp.\n" +
                        "Non-GMO, Vegan friendly, CO2 Extracted.\n" +
                        "Fast-Acting.\n" +
                        "Peppermint flavour available.\n" +
                        "Sourced from High-CBD Hemp cultivated in the US.\n" +
                        "Strict GMP Manufacturing & Quality Control process.\n" +
                        "Public Third-Party Lab Test Results.",
                    "https://i1.wp.com/benefitcbduk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/what-are-the-benefits-of-cbd.jpg?fit=1200%2C1200&ssl=1", 49.99);

        ProductObject productObject2 = new ProductObject("Koi CBD – Multi-Purpose CBD Vape or Tincture Oil (250MG-1000MG)",
                "A novel Cannabidiol product from Koi CBD, the Multi-Purpose CBD Vape E-liquid or Tincture CBD Oil. Can’t decide whether to buy Vape or CBD Oil? Why not do both?",
                " No Flavoured Additives.\n" +
                        "> Non-Psychoactive (Zero THC).\n" +
                        "> Hexane Free.\n" +
                        "> GMO Free.\n" +
                        "> Pesticide Free.\n" +
                        "> Multi-Purpose – Perfect vape juice to add to other e-liquids and ideal for use as a tincture or to add to other foods/drinks.",
                "https://i2.wp.com/benefitcbduk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/koi-cbd-250-gold.png?fit=1080%2C1080&ssl=1", 44.99);

            productObjectArrayList.add(productObject);
            productObjectArrayList.add(productObject2);

            ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, R.layout.productlistlayout, productObjectArrayList);
            lstProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.basket:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Basket.class));
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

ProductAdapter.java

```js
package com.example.jack.cbdcalculator;

public class ProductObject {

    String productName, productDescription, productExtraInfo, productImageUrl;
    Double productPrice;

    public ProductObject(String productName, String productDescription, String productExtraInfo, String productImageUrl, Double productPrice) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.productExtraInfo = productExtraInfo;
        this.productImageUrl = productImageUrl;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductExtraInfo() {
        return productExtraInfo;
    }

    public void setProductExtraInfo(String productExtraInfo) {
        this.productExtraInfo = productExtraInfo;
    }

    public String getProductImageUrl() {
        return productImageUrl;
    }

    public void setProductImageUrl(String productImageUrl) {
        this.productImageUrl = productImageUrl;
    }

    public Double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(Double productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly don't put your listview inside scrollview...scrollview itself have scroll behaviour..might be that the problem

Comment: But a scrollview can only have one child, that's why I need the listview to store other objects

Comment: Ignore me, I'm an idiot, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProductListLayout.xml`, the first `android:layout_height="match_parent"` declaration, instead of having the attribute match parent, it should have a constant, or any other size that doesn't take the enterity of the screen. Right now, you see that white space because only the first element is displayed, as there is no room for others. Try changing it to maybe `200dp`.